# angularjs replace newline from an object copied with angular.copy()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to replace all line breaks in an object property which is being filled using angular.copy from a json object but for some reason the value can not be modified.

```
angular.copy(data, vm.candidate);
console.log(vm.candidate.Comments.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

The output is still: hi\nhow\nare\nu\n

But if I set this output in a variable

```
var xx = "hi\nhow\nare\nu\n";
console.log(xx.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

The output is: hi
how
are
u
 as expected.

Basically, I am trying to do something like this:

```
 vm.candidate.Comments=$sce.trustAsHtml(vm.candidate.Comments.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

In the view:

```
<p ng-bind-html="candCtrl.candidate.Comments"></p>
```

Trying to get the right outoput in the view:

"hi how are u"

Any ideas why it is not working?

A jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6vs7ohk/2/)

Comment: Are you sure, that `vm.candidate.Comments` has **\n**?

Comment: yes. the output  for console.log(vm.candidate.Comments.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')); is : hi\nhow\nare\nu\n

Comment: That is really strange. Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, could u have a look this jsfiddle I just created https://jsfiddle.net/x6vs7ohk/2/

Comment: you're not operating on the copied object though, so title is kinda misleading.

Comment: Y do u have double backslashes in your comments string?? if you have single backslash it comes fine. instead of replacing it with breaks if in case there are double backslashes try this  $scope.car2=angular.copy($scope.car.Comments.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')); else if only one newline character like \n no need to replace it will be displayed properly. https://jsfiddle.net/x6vs7ohk/3/

Comment: didnt realise, it had two backslashes. But actually yes, it was the problem.what is totally weird is if I see the json returned using fiddler the property only has single backslashes, but in the raw response tab (fiddler) it has two backslashes. so I dont know why, and the db has only single ones. Strange.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*Notice, I'm working with the jsfiddle provided in the comments to the original question.

Basically, you're using `angular.copy` wrong.

According to the angular docs at [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

`[angular.copy] Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.`

You're trying to copy a `string`.
The solution is to copy the entire object and then use your regex to replace `\n` with `<br/>`

your code:

```
   function LoginController($scope) {
     $scope.car2 = {};
     $scope.car = { "ID": 3, "Comments": "hi\\nhow\\nare\\nu\\n","RatingID": 2,"Rating":"Unsure"};
     $scope.car2=angular.copy($scope.car.Comments.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));  
 }
```

working code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6vs7ohk/4/)):

```
   function LoginController($scope) {
     $scope.car2 = {};
     $scope.car = { "ID": 3, "Comments": "hi\nhow\nare\nu\n","RatingID": 2,"Rating":"Unsure"}
     $scope.car2 = angular.copy($scope.car)
     $scope.car2 = $scope.car2.Comments.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @nadavvandan. I will refactor my code to use your approach. However the issue was, for some reason the json returned by the server has double backslashes even if the db has single ones. So the regex was failing. just realised when implementing the example in fiddle.